# Proper way to format timestamp in bash

Tags: linux, bash, rhel

So I need to create an output file for an outside contractor containing a list of filenames from a directory and creation dates in a specific format like this:

```
FileName     YYYYmmDDHHMMSS
```

So far I've come up with:

```
find ./ -type f -printf " %f %a\n"
```

which returns:

FIleName Fri Apr 21 18:21:15.0458585800 2017

Or:

```
ls -l | awk {'print  $9" "$6" "$7" "$8'}
```

which returns:

FileNAme Apr 21 18:21

But neither is quite the output i need as it needs to be purely numerical and include seconds.

Keeping in mind that the list of files could be very large so efficiency is a priority, how can i get this output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this

```
find ./ -type f -printf " %f %AY%Am%Ad%AH%AM%AS\n" |sed -e 's/\.[0-9]*$//'
```

(`sed` is needed to remove fractional part after seconds)

(Edit) with `ls` it will be:

```
ls -l --time-style=+%Y%m%d%H%M%S |awk {'print $7" "$6'}
```